# What is the equivalent for flash/actionscirpt based addEventListener, removeEventListener and dispatchEvent in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, actionscript

AS some one porting code from actionscript to IOS, We have a lot of custom components that follow the event dispatching mechanism in Flash/Actionscript:

E.g. dispatcher:

```
dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.DRAG_DROP));
```

Consumer:

```
dispatcher.addEventListener(CustomEvent.DRAG_DROP, actionHandler);

private function actionHandler(event:CustomEvent):void {
            trace("actionHandler: " + event);
        }
```

I know of NSNotificationCenter, KVO pattern, action-target, but none seem to be an exact match?

Where would I define CustomEvent? CustomEvent.DRAG_DROP? and how would the consumer listen for the event? How would a consumer know of all the events that a dispatcher can dispatch? I do not wish to use a delegate because there could be multiple consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closes way I know is selectors ...

```
// store event handler
SEL targetHandler;

// firing an event
[targetHandler performSelector:targetHandler withObject:eventObj];

// event handler in the listening class
- (void) onStuffHappened: (Event*) event
{

}
```

that's obviously a quick thought, I would extend NSObject and store handlers in NSMutableArray then run performSelector on all the stored handlers ... something like that

or you can use delegates for a cleaner way.

Comment: Do you know how to define custom selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is done with a list of delegates. If you want a multiple consumers, define a protocol (just like you would for a delegate), and then create an array of those objects. When you want to communicate with all of the listeners iterate through the list of listeners sending the event to each one.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of this? Or is this an approach that is not very common? This seems like a very common thing to do and its surprising there is no built in/recommended way?